# What would be a good alternative to multiple inheritance in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

Say Bob is a human male

So I inherit both human and male.

Now say I want to implement human as inheritance

```
@interface BobLike : human
```

And then I want to create a male protocol

```
@protocol male
```

So,

We got

```
@interface BobLike : human <male>
```

Okay, so far so good. I can make  a class like behavior by putting male interface in a protocol. Something like

```
@protocol male
-(void) growBeard;
-(void) playVideoGames;
@end

@interface human (male) <male>

@end
```

Here implementation of growBeard and playVideogames will be enjoyed by BobLike

What about if latter I want to inherit male. Say I want to create another "class like object" called normalMale

Say normalMale has longer beard and hence I will override

```
@protocol normalMale :male
//-(void) growBeard; //No need to be declared because we already declare that as in male protocol
//-(void) playVideoGames; //No need to be declared because we already declare that as in male protocol
@end

@interface NSObject (singleton) <male>

@end
@end

@interface human (normalMale) <normalMale>

@end
```

Then I reimplemented
    -(void) growBeard;
    -(void) playVideoGames;

as usual. But which one will be called? growBeard, playVideoGames, etc?

Comment: Yoy, that question really changed over the last five minutes...

Comment: Yes, that would work - given that I understood your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct - instead of inheriting from multiple classes, you can inherit from one (or none), and inherit the rest through adapting protocols. If `human` and `male` are at the same level logically, you may want to make both of them protocols, like this:

```
@interface Bob : NSObject <human,male>
```

If you need to share implementation, define categories on `human` and `male`, and put implementations there. This would have an effect similar to adding methods to `Bob`.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the use of categories for shared implementations on protocols.

Answer (score 0):

like JAVA,Objective-C does not support multiple inheritance.But as in java interfaces are provided as alternative to Multiple Inheritance,In objective C protocols are provided to use as an Alternative to Multiple Inheritance.So you can use protocols here.

Here is good [tutorial of Protocols](http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)

Comment: Java supports multiple inheritance?  C++ does, but not Java.

Comment: Protocols are not the only alternative to multiple inheritance. Often enough you are better off using class clusters (specific factory pattern).

Comment: @Hercules The first sentence can be read two ways. You probably wanted to say "Like Java, Objective-C does not support multiple inheritance." But one could also read it as "Objective-C does not support multiple inheritance like Java [does]", which would be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have NormalMale subclass Male which in turn subclasses Human. It all depends on the logical structure of your data. Don't forget you also have categories which sometimes can be useful in situations like these.